# Twilio: multiple-step recording

Tags: twilio

I want to get four related pieces of information from a caller, and get recordings of each. Do I need to implement this as four separate calls (Say/Record pairs in the XML file) to the Twilio API and my web endpoint (the Record 'action' or StatusCallback)?  I'm using Python and Flask, but examples in other languages and frameworks would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Twilo evangelist here.

Four separate recordings is probably the easiest way to do what you want.

```
<Say>Begin Recording 1</Say>
<Record>
<Say>Begin Recording 2</Say>
<Record>
<Say>Begin Recording 3</Say>
<Record>
<Say>Begin Recording 4</Say>
<Record>
<Say>Thanks for recording four things</Say>
```

The hard part is going to be knowing that the user actually gave you the right information, so you might want to think about adding a step at the end of your call flow that allows your caller to hear their recording and choose to re-record the info if they want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Devin. That was my best guess. How can I distinguish the four?  I'm trying something like "<Record method='GET' action='/callback?step=1' />".